# In clustering, what is the analogous of the centroid that uses the median instead of the mean?

Tags: clustering, mean, median

The centroid of a cluster is defined as centroid. It is defined as the mean of each dimension across all samples of the cluster.

What is the analogous that uses the median of each dimension? As far as I know, a similar concept is the medoid, which needs to be an actual sample of the cluster.

Comment: Centroid is multivariate mean, quite univocal concept. Median in multivariate space can be defined differently (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Multivariate_median). Medoid is defined univocally up to its formula, but the formula is based on distance in space, and that disctance could be defined differently (e.g. euclidean or manhattan).

Comment: Thanks @ttnphns. I think that my idea of the centroid-like point is the *marginal* multivariate median. Although I don't know if the spatial multivariate median could be a better estimate.

Comment: @ttnphns could you please put it as answer?

Comment: fbrundu, thank you. But I don't feel like having given anything special deserving to be an answer.

Comment: Well, I thought that multivariate median, also with the corresponding description of alternatives, could be a suitable answer. Why wouldn't be it?